# Django get_object_or_404 with select_related causes form checkbox widget weird behavior : Django 1.4 bug?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-1.4

I come with a really strange Django 1.4 behaviour wich sounds like a bug to me. I looked anywhere if someone experienced it, but didn't find anything.

My concern is about **Django form creation using ModelForm**, with a model containing boolean field.

Let `Post` and `Topic` two models wich should look like :

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    my_bool = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Post(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='posts')
```

Now, I'm gonna try to generate a form using TopicForm a class definied elsewhere :

```
post = Post.objects.get(pk=id_post)
f = TopicForm(instance=post.topic)
print f
```

It works fine : if in DB `my_bool` is False, the checkbox is *not* checked. If `my_bool` is True, the checkbox is checked. Here is the result :

```
<p><label for="id_my_bool">my_bool:</label> <input type="checkbox" name="my_bool" id="id_my_bool" /></p>
```

### The problem !

OK, so here is the problem : if I use `get_object_or_404` to get my `Post` object, then `my_bool` field **will always be checked** ! Look at this :

```
post = get_object_or_404(Post.objects.select_related('topic'), pk=id_post)
f = TopicForm(instance=post.topic)
print f
```

Output (weird) :

```
<p><label for="id_my_bool">my_bool:</label> <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="my_bool" value="0" id="id_my_bool" /></p>
```

Nota : I tryed several other ways to get the `Post` object, which **all work fine** :

- `post = Post.objects.filter(pk=id_post)[0]`
- `post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=id_post)`
- `post = Post.objects.get(pk=id_post)`

The only thing which makes it bug is :

```
post = get_object_or_404(Post.objects.select_related('topic'), pk=id_post)
```

### Comments

- With Django 1.3, there wasn't any problem with it : only Django 1.4 makes it bug.
- I found some Django 1.4 bugs which seemed to be related, like :

  - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17747
  - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17114
  - http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/7d895b2f5fc9ef4b
- I do not use MySQL GIS backend, but `django.db.backends.mysql`.

Have you got any idea ?

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: You should consider opening a ticket at https://code.djangoproject.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same bug in my app and found [opened ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15040).
It seems the main problem is in pair **select_related & MySQL**: MySQL returns integers for booleans but Django can't associate them with corresponding model when using select_related; consequently, **CheckboxInput** gets value 0 instead of False and treats it like value in checkbox list.

You can:

1. use patch from ticket;
2. or avoid using **select_related**;
3. or patch **CheckboxInput** widget:

   ```
   class SingleCheckboxInput(forms.CheckboxInput):
       def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
           if value in (0, 1):
               value = bool(value)
           return super(SingleCheckboxInput, self).render(name, value, attrs)

   class TopicForm(django.forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
           model = Topic
           widgets = {'my_bool': SingleCheckboxInput}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I see a similar bug, where if I uncheck all boxes, POST data is empty! if I uncehck only one, POST data arrives. Instead of calling get_object_or_404(), examine your inbound request.POST data.